# Maintain scroll position when switching between BottomNavigationBar tabs in nested navigation using Navigator 2.0 API

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

How to Maintain scroll position when switching between `BottomNavigationBar` tabs in nested navigation using Navigator 2.0 API?

In the [Navigator 2.0 introduction article in medium](https://medium.com/flutter/learning-flutters-new-navigation-and-routing-system-7c9068155ade), the author shared an example for Nested Routing* which can be viewed in this [dartpad (modified with extra books to observe the behavior)](https://dartpad.dev/0fbdf1a3e4b0ffc6e1b433f0fd351cf0).

When scrolling down in the home *(list of books)*, then navigating to the settings, and then returning again to home, the scroll position is lost.

I've tried to add `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` with `bool get wantKeepAlive => true;` in both `_BooksListScreenState` as well as `_AppShellState` but that didn't help.

How one can maintain the state of each page in a nested/parallel scenario such in the given example?

What's also confusing to me is that `RouterDelegate` isn't maintaining the states for `MaterialPage` which is used in the given example and which has `maintainState = true` as a default.

* *[original nested router (gist)](https://gist.github.com/johnpryan/bbca91e23bbb4d39247fa922533be7c9)*

Comment: did you solve this problem? I'm facing this problem and I haven't found a solution.

Comment: @julianzapata I bet since u found this question. I haven't found a solution at the time. Maybe you gotta check one of the several navigation packages if they've a solution. There are more than [30 of them](https://twitter.com/RydMike/status/1471631328026279941)